# osx Caught exception: exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, sql-server, macos

I'm trying to connect to sql server from my mac osx from a php file.  I keep getting this error:

```
Caught exception: exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'
```

I installed everything from this website - http://blog.andyhunt.info/2013/11/29/php-mssql-pdo_dblib-freetds-support-on-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/ but nothing seems to work.  It fails at this part in the PHP

```
$serverName = "xx.xx.xx";
new PDO("dblib:host=$serverName;dbname='xx'", "xx", "xx");
```

Comment: I'm trying to connect to SQL Server, not mysql

Comment: MSSQL.  But the link you sent provides instructions for windows.  I'm trying to run the PHP file on a Mac connecting to an MS SQL Server.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have the PDO Driver Installed?

Comment: I have this in the PHPInfo() - PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, pgsql

Comment: Can you please send me the link of the duplicate question?  The links you sent are for different problems.